# Pandas fill Mutliindex column data frame from single index column data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames with same row index.

First dataframe :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2023-12-31','2024-01-31'], ['myvalue1', 'myvalue2']]))
```

Second dataframe :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'], data=
                   {'myvalue1':[2,3, 4], 'myvalue2':[6,7,8]})
```

Remembering that row indices are the same, I wanted to fill first dataframe with second, like that :

```
df1.loc[:,(slice(None),'myvalue1')] = df2['myvalue1']
df1.loc[:,(slice(None),'myvalue2')] = df2['myvalue2']
```

I get the error : ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Expected result for df1 :

```
    2023-12-31          2024-01-31
   myvalue1   myvalue2  myvalue1    myvalue2
a   2          6          2           6
b   3          7          3           7
c   4          8          4           8
```

Do you know how to proceed (avoiding for loop) ?

Comment: read notice: [mre]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can avoid using an intermediate template (*i.e, the input* `df1`) but if you can't, here is one option with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)/[`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) :

```
df1 = (
    df2
        .reindex(df1.columns.get_level_values(1), axis=1)
        .set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1)
)
```

Output :

```
  2023-12-31          2024-01-31         
    myvalue1 myvalue2   myvalue1 myvalue2
a          2        6          2        6
b          3        7          3        7
c          4        8          4        8
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using Numpy:

```
df1.loc[:, (slice(None), 'myvalue1')] = (
    np.tile(
        df2['myvalue1'].values,
        (df1.columns.levshape[0], 1)
    ).T
)
```